# Need to connect Azure Function App to Azure App Service (WCF)

Tags: azure, wcf-data-services, wcf-binding, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

A WCF service (.svc) is running on Azure App Service.
An Azure App function is created separately.

Need to know how to call a method present in App Service (.svc) from an Azure App Function.

Answer (score 0):

Just expose the WCF Service Restful and do Http requests against it:

5 steps for make wcf restfull - http://www.topwcftutorials.net/2013/09/simple-steps-for-restful-service.html